# How to graph a cumulative subtraction on Wolfram Alpha

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to graph a timing algorithm that I'd been using (that did essentially the opposite of what I wanted). I apologize if I'm not using the correct name to refer to it.

Essentially it was timer = 100, timer = timer - level, where level increases from 0 to 50 etc.

For example; 100-1 = 99, 99-2 = 97, 97-3 = 94, 94-4 = 90, etc...

To give you some examples of the kind of graph I'd like, input the following two which were used to create the correct algorithm (a sort of exponential decay);

y=100\cdot e^{-0.05x} with x from 0 to 50

y=100*0.95^{x} with x from 0 to 50

(I'm writing a little article about the improved timer, and I'd like to include graphs of the old and new algorithms for comparison.) Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: A friend figured it out finally: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D500-%280.5x%28x%2B1%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIRST I changed it to going from $500$

Secondly, it actually gives an alternate interpretation for the summation, and once THAT is punched in, guess what ;)

y=500-(0.5x(x+1)) from x=0 to x=31

[Wolframalpha input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D500-%280.5x%28x%2B1%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D31)

It's too bad that I couldn't get the $x\gt0$ plotting to work with sigma notation, but this works :)

y=100-( sum j, j=1 to x)

[Wolframalpha input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D100-%28+sum+j%2C+j%3D1+to+x%29)